# java.net.MalformedURLException error when I try to apply a stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, xslt

I have a problem when I try to use a stylesheet, it gives me this error:

```
07-Jul-2015 16:06:53.811 INFO [http-apr-8084-exec-7] mx.com.vw.servlet.filters.StylizerFilter.doFilter Stylizing: xslt/semaphore.xsl with download: false filename:null mimetype:text/html
---
CONSULTA
(Ubicación del error desconocida)java.net.MalformedURLException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mx.com.vw.servlet.filters.StylizerFilter.doFilter(StylizerFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In my index I ask for the results from a servlet and apply this stylesheet, the sintax is this:

```
<iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/semaphore?cmd=retrieve&stylesheet=xslt/semaphore.xsl"
                    width="100%" height="100%"
                    scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

If I don't pass the `&stylesheet=xslt/semaphore.xsl` part, I get the results obviously with not style, that's why I think it has something to do with my xsl, the funny thing is that I run perfectly fine the same app using tomcat 6, and this is with tomcat 8.
Is there some problem with the version of tomcat I'm using?
Also  I'm using Xalan 2.7 
Any ideas?

Comment: instead of `stylesheet=xslt/semaphore.xsl` can you try `stylesheet=xslt%2Fsemaphore.xsl` ?

Comment: `&stylesheet=xslt/semaphore.xsl` s/b `&amp;stylesheet=xslt/semaphore.xsl`